# Getting OutOfMemoryError When taking More Than 13 Pictures

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-camera

I am Getting OutOfMemoryError When I take More Than 13 Pictures. and It Crashes after restart it is allowing me to take another 13 Pictures

I am restarting the app after Crash.

Here My StactTrace

```
PID: 9656                                                            
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=259476KB, Allocated=246686KB)                                                                                
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)                                                                           
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1137)                                                                                  
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1109)                                                                                 
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1076)                                                                                
at 
com.redmonk.bricapp.enterprise.cameramodule.control.CameraPreview.
initFocusDrawingTools(CameraPreview.java:114)                                                                                 
at 
com.redmonk.bricapp.enterprise.cameramodule.control.CameraPreview.
surfaceChanged(CameraPreview.java:139)                                                                                  
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:583)                                                                                  
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)                                                                                  
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)                                                                                  
at 
android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)                                                                                  
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1993)                                                                                  
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)                                                                                  
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5905)                                                                                  
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:807)                                                                                  
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:601)                                                                                  
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:562)                                                                                  
at 
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run
(Choreographer.java:791                                                                                  
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)                                                                                  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)                                                                                  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)                                                                                  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                                  
at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:896)                                                                                 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)                                                                                  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

A method where I am Getting Exception I am restarting the app after a crash

```
private void focused() {
focusing = false;
String checkBeep =  Prefs.getString("BeepDone","");
try {
if (!checkBeep.equals("true")) {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer2, mMediaPlayer;
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer = 
MediaPlayer.create(WebServiceSingleTon.getInstance().mainActivity,R.raw.
beepnew);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
mMediaPlayer.start();
Prefs.putString("BeepDone", "true");
}
if (focusCallback != null) {
    focusCallback.onFocused(camera);
}
}catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
cp.initiateSmoothRestart();// I am restarting app Here
}catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Project-wide Gradle settings.

```
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m - 
XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# org.gradle.parallel=true
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: Show the code how you take photos.

Comment: You probably leak the Bitmaps - you should save your images to a file and let garbage collector or manually recycle the photos, no phone will be able to hold that many display size bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use scaled bitmaps if you want to keep your images in RAM.
This works for me:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
myImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false)); // here 120 - is height and width of scaled bitmap
```